# asp.core2 как настроить маршруты для нескольких перегрузок Get

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp

Я хочу чтобы у меня был контроллер с несколькими перегрузками действия Get и чтобы можно было к ним строить HttpGet запросы следующим образом.

```
/api/Attribute?name=abc
/api/Attribute?name=abc&id=2
/api/Attribute
```

Контроллер имеет следующий вид

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Attribute")]
public class AttributeController:Controller
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    [Route("")]
    public List<ProductAttrVm> Get()
     ...
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[controller]/{name}/{id}")]
    public List<ProductAttrVm> Get(string name, int id)
    ...
    [HttpGet("api/[controller]/{name}")]
    public List<ProductAttrVm> Get(string name)
```

Проблема в том, что всегда вызывается действие без параметров

`public List<ProductAttrVm> Get()`

Как мне правильно настроить маршруты у перегрузок методов Get чтобы можно было использовать HttpGet запросы, которые я описал выше?

Comment: попробуйте вести запрос вида api/attribute/abc/2 и запрос api/attributeabc. Что у вас выводится?

Comment: Пару замечаний вам. 1. `[Route("api/Attribute")]` - можно просто заменить на `[Route("api/[controller]")]`. 2. `[HttpGet][Route("[controller]/{name}/{id}")]` - во первых, писать контроллер тут бессмысленно. Во вторых это все можно объединить в `[HttpGet("{name}/{id}")]`. Также... Зачем вам столько методов? Сделайте один и в нем проверяйте, заданы ли name/id. А также вы путаете запросы, путями вы задаете, что хотите что то вроде `/api/Attribute/aaa/bbb`, запросам с видом `/api/Attribute?aaa=bbb` не надо задавать не каких маршрутов.

Comment: `?name=abc&id=2` - это query. `/name/id` - это path.

Comment: @АлексейКлещевников да api/attribute/abc/2 будет работать, но хотелось бы именно вашего параметры а http запросе передавать. Т.к это более явно и понятно для клиентов которые будут использовать api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте один метод со следующей сигнатурой:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<ProductAttrVm> Get([FromQuery] string name, [FromQuery] int? id)
```

И внутри проверяйте полученные значения на `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Для тех кто все еще ищет:
Не обязательно принимать отправленные параметры в качестве аргументов, можно вытащить их из обьекта Reques:

```
    string altitudeString = Request.Query.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "altitude").Value;
```

Comment: Здесь больше:https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/5.2.php